# How to write code for insertion and deletion of table data with many buttons from front-end?

Tags: java, html, database, jsp

I write code for one web page in jsp. Here, it shows the table values. Every table row contain two buttons. One for deletion, another for insertion of another table.   How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

make diffent function for insertion and deletion in in different class like

```
 Class DC()
{
   public void insert()
    {
      your code
    }
  public void delete()
    {
      your code
    }

}
```

then use in jsp code

```
<td> <input type="button" value="insert" onsubmit=<% insert1(); %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I think i to use links 
try this idea :

add in your table  a row like this :

```
 <td style=" width:  100px;"><a class=" " 
href="SERVLET-NAME?DATA=/*WHAT-YOU-WANT*/&DATA2=/*WHAT-YOU-WANT*/">DELETE</a>
```

//you can put ${} instead of /*WHAT-YOU-WANT*/

then in your servlet take the data a perform the wanted Action on database for example

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
String DATA1 = request.getParameter("DATA");
String DATA2 = request.getParameter("DATA2");
Database obj= new Database();
obj.delete(DATA1,DATA2);
//...

}
```